# TanStack Query API call gets called multiple times regardless of staleTime

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm using TanStack Query (React Query) to fetch data in my React application. I have the following code in my Home component:

This is a educational project im working on to practice this package.

```
export default function Home() {
  const query = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['auth-user', 1],
    queryFn: fetch('http://localhost/api/user').then(res => res.json()).catch(err => err.response),
    // staleTime: 10000,
    // enabled: false,
    // retry: false
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <HeaderSection />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the API call to http://localhost/api/user gets called multiple times on page load, even though I've set staleTime to 10000 milliseconds (10 seconds).

However, when I set enabled to false, the API call is triggered only once, which is the expected behavior.

I noticed that this issue occurs only when the API call fails. I tried disabling retries by setting retry to false, which reduced the number of times the API call was made, but it still gets called twice on page load.

Can someone explain why the staleTime option is not working as expected, and the API call is being fired multiple times on page load, especially when the API call fails?

Additional Information:

- I'm using the latest version of TanStack Query (react-query@3.x)
- The API call is a simple GET request to fetch the current user's data
- I've tried different values for staleTime (e.g., 5000, 30000), but the issue persists
- Disabling retries (retry: false) reduces the number of times the API call is made, but it still gets called twice on page load

Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have enabled Strict mode? Usually in Strict mode hooks are called twice.

Comment: No i've disabled strict mode

Comment: Try using the queryFn like this, `queryFn: () => fetch('').then()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the code provided there is returning of the Promise res.json(). The correct code is:

```
const query = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["homes"],
    queryFn: fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/homes")
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("request executed")
            res.json()
        })
        .then((json) => {
            return json
        })
        .catch((err) => err.response),
});
```

useQuery needs the json/data, which comes from the Promise res.json(), not the Promise itself.

EDIT: I saw edited question from the OP - the version of react-query is v3.x

The working code for this is:

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query";

const fetchHomes = async () => {
   const resp = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/homes");
   console.log("fetched")
   if (!resp.ok) {
       throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
   }
   return resp.json(); 
};

export default function Home() {
    const query = useQuery("homes", fetchHomes)

    return <p>Some paragraph</p>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but the issue still remains.

Comment: I edited my response, I saw the version